# Composer doens't update 'laravel/framework' package

Tags: laravel, composer-php, plesk

I'm trying to update my composer dependencies as I'm experiencing a weird error that in my Debug Pages I get the Symfony Page but not the Laravel one. As I tried to update my composer packages I saw that composer doens't even updates the `laravel/framework` package.

**Composer output**

```
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Package manifest generated successfully.
Installing dependencies from lock file
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
39 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
      "ext-json": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm using Plesk and *can't* access SSH.

Comment: And **why** should some package be updated? Usually, you run such operations on a local developer machine with full access to all tools, and deploy it to your server when your work is done

Comment: When you run 'php artisan --version', what version is output?

Comment: @NicoHaase I wouldn't usually upload the vendor folder...I would typically do a composer update on the server itself to avoid having to transfer that hefty file data.

Comment: You should never run `composer update` on a live system - copy `composer.lock` to your server and run `composer install`  if you don't want to transfer the vendor directory

Comment: I wasn't really referring to a production server since that's not what was stated by the OP, however even if I acknowledge your point, I was referencing your statement where you said, 'Usually, you run such operations on a local developer machine with full access to all tools, and deploy it to your server when your work is done.'  Usually, I would not upload the vendor folder, ever.  Usually I would do the composer update on my DEV server to download the dependencies, or composer install if you prefer.

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried computer update to check, if that the cause of my project not working correctly as I can't move images, the Laravel Stack Trace is not shown etc.

(at)Mark Cross Laravel Framework 7.21.0

It is a development server, but the administrator doesn't allow us ssh

Comment: @MarkCross in all of our projects, we don't want to rely on Composer being installed on a remote server - it does not belong there. So we compile everything and upload a fully runnable application to the production server

Comment: 7.21 is the latest Laravel release so I would say that it is updating the framework most likely. @NicoHaase That's great, but I think we're talking about the OP's question which clearly involves working with a server with Composer already installed on it.

Comment: Hm, thats mad. Is there any possible reason why Laravel then would not show the Laravel Error Screen but the Symfony one?

Comment: Laravel does use the Symfony framework, but without further investigation it would be impossible to tell what's going on.  Possibly think about either rewording the question or posting a new one with more details if you could?

Comment: @MarkCross Tell me what you need and I will post it in another question!

Comment: Not to be jerky, but you would need to describe exactly what you're trying to do, what code you're using, what you've tried to resolve the error, what causes the error to occur and preferably show the related code blocks (like your model, controller, etc).  It would be hard to know anything without most of the information.  Imagine you're a mechanic and someone saying, 'My car is broken, can you fix it?'.  Again, not trying to be condescending, just need all the information to work on the problem.